# How to run a date range query using mongodb REST API.?

Tags: mongodb

Iam trying to run a query to mongodb using the REST API as documented here -http://docs.mongolab.com/restapi/.

My query looks like this 
`https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/dbname/collections/collectionname?apiKey=key&q={"postdate" :{"$gte": {"$date" : "2015-05-24T18:40:57Z"}, "$lt": {"$date" : "2015-05-28T18:40:57Z"}}}&l=50`

If you see; Iam trying to pass a date range in the query. Would passing date like this work or there is some other format specific to the REST API.?

Answer (score 0):

Try this url for the get request:

```
url = 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/db-name/collections/table-name?q={"created": {"$gt":{"$date":"2015-09-15T12:16:41.495Z"},"$lt":{"$date":"2015-10-20T12:16:41.495Z"}}}&apiKey=YOURAPIKEY'
```